# Want software tool to do relative linking between pdf files

Tags: pdf, reference-management

I am using the current release of Windows 10 on a PC.

I have about 3,000 pdf files that are in a sub-directory. I'd like to crosslink the pdf files to one another using relative addressing. Thus if I move the files to a different directory the cross-linking would still work.

> The gist is that I'd like to link the references in one PDF file to the pdf file of the reference itself. Also using relative addressing like ".\ref_1.pdf" rather than "c:\program files\Zotero\references\ref_1.pdf".

Adobe seems to have removed any ability to do linking from the reader. As I remember with Adobe reader  you could only do absolute linking.

(1) If I got a subscription to Adobe could I use relative linking?

(2) Any other tool that would do this?